# Can I use clickhouse as key-value storage?

Tags: key-value-store, clickhouse

Is it possible to use clickhouse as key-value storage, were data is regularly overwritten, but rarely read? What engine should I use if this is possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ClickHouse isn't built for that use case and it deliberately says that in the home page of its document.

> When NOT to use ClickHouse
>
> 1. Transactional workloads (OLTP)
> 2. Key-value access with high request rate
> 3. Blob or document storage
> 4. Over-normalized data

However, if the QPS is low, you can still achieve good latency scores for point queries. ClickHouse also provides multiple kinds of Dictionaries that may be better serve as the external key-value storage. There is also a `StorageJoin` engine that supports `joinGet` function similar to redis' `HGET` operation. After this [PR](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/3973) you can overwrite the existing keys in `StorageJoin`.

## update

[PR](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/3973) is merged. Here is an isolated example.

First populate a StorageJoin table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE my_fancy_kv_store (s String, x Array(UInt8), k UInt64)
ENGINE = Join(ANY, LEFT, s);

INSERT INTO my_fancy_kv_store VALUES ('abc', [0], 1), ('def', [1, 2], 2);
```

Then you can use it as a dictionary (key-value):

```
SELECT joinGet('my_fancy_kv_store', 'x', 'abc');
SELECT joinGet('my_fancy_kv_store', 'k', 'def');
```

Comment: What engine should I use if this is possible?

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00800_versatile_storage_join.sql#L33    hope you get the idea

Comment: no, I don't. If you provide an isolated example, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[EmbeddedRocksDB](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/embedded-rocksdb/) table engine was recently added and can help.

More can be found here: https://kb.altinity.com/engines/altinity-kb-embeddedrocksdb-and-dictionary

In my tests, compared to `MergeTree`, I see `EmbeddedRocksDB` handle 10-20x higher QPS amouting to 10-100x faster response rates.

It can vary by usecase, but its good enough for me to not bother looking out for separate `Redis / RocksDB / DynamoDB` installations (since having KV stores inside CH helps to join across MT and EmbeddedRocksDB, and I don't really need to scale up to limits of redis / DDB)